# full example of validation in the sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Please give someone a full example of validation in the sails.js here.
Of course, with custom error messages
For example, suppose we have a model called the book and we want to get
information from the userv as request and save it in the database.

Please based on Sails.js version 1.0.

I try the sails-custom-validation-messaging package but it's not working properly.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-custom-validation-messages

Comment: [Show us what you've tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I created a little helper hook for validation in Sails 1.x:

https://github.com/xtrinch/sails-hook-validation-ev

In its most simplest form with using blueprint routes, it works by adding a validate function to a model:

`Todo.js:`

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    title: {    
      type: 'string',   
      required: true    
    },  
     description: { 
      type: 'string',   
      required: true    
    },
  },

  validate: (req) => {
    req.check('title')
      .exists()
      .isLength({ min: 1 }).withMessage('must be at least 5 chars long');
    req.check('description').exists();
  }

};
```

Example response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "location": "params",
            "param": "title",
            "msg": "Invalid value"
        },
        {
            "location": "params",
            "param": "title",
            "msg": "must be at least 5 chars long"
        }
    ]
}
```

Check API is taken from express-validator in order to not reinvent the wheel.

For more options and advanced usage, see full `readme.md` of the hook.